# How to keep information about an app in Android?

Tags: android

I want to know if its possible to keep information about an app in a while for example.

I have an app that access this file and get information about the choices that the user have made. For example:

I have a button for many events (event is a model), and i want to know if the user clicked in the button even after the application restarts.

I know that it is possible to keep information about login and password. Is possible to do something like this with other information?

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Thanks guys. I  think SharedPreferences is the best approach for my application.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Shared Preferences**. Like so:

Create these methods for use, or just use the content inside of the methods whenever you want:

```
public String getPrefValue()
{
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preferenceName", 0);
  String str = sp.getString("myStore","TheDefaultValueIfNoValueFoundOfThisKey");
  return str;
}

public void writeToPref(String thePreference)
{
  SharedPreferences.Editor pref =getSharedPreferences("preferenceName",0).edit();
  pref.putString("myStore", thePreference);
  pref.commit();
}
```

You could call them like this:

```
// when they click the button:
writeToPref("theyClickedTheButton");

if (getPrefValue().equals("theyClickedTheButton"))
{
   // they have clicked the button
}
else if (getPrefValue().equals("TheDefaultValueIfNoValueFoundOfThisKey"))
{
   // this preference has not been created (have not clicked the button)
}
else
{
   // this preference has been created, but they have not clicked the button
}
```

Explanation of the code:

`"preferenceName"` is the name of the preference you're referring to and therefore has to be the same every time you access that specific preference. eg: `"password"`, `"theirSettings"`

"myStore" refers to a specific `String` stored in that preference and their can be multiple.
eg: you have preference `"theirSettings"`, well then `"myStore"` could be `"soundPrefs"`, `"colourPrefs"`, `"language"`, etc.

**Note:** you can do this with `boolean`, `integer`, etc.

All you have to do is change the `String` storing and reading to `boolean`, or whatever type you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to save your data in Android.

To write your information

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("user_Id",userid.getText().toString());
editor.putString("user_Password",password.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

To read above information

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = prfs.getString("user_Id", "");
```

In iOS NSUserDefaults is used to do the same

//For saving

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:your_username forKey:@"user_Id"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

//For retrieving

```
NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_Id"];
```

Hope it helps.