# Sending text from intent to another intent

Tags: java, android

This is the write activity. In here I want to write a text and after clicking a button I want this text to appear in a new activity called read activity.

```
public class Write extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    EditText text; TextView retrive1;
    public static String filename="Mysharedstring" ;
    SharedPreferences someData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.write);
        setupVariables();
        someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    }

    private void setupVariables()
    {
        Button sav= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        Button ret= (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrive);
        text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        retrive1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        ret.setOnClickListener(this);
        sav.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String stringdata= text.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
        editor.putString("sharedString", stringdata);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

*I don't know what to write in the read activity.*

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //???
}
```

Comment: Did you check the Android documentation? You can check here (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and here (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) that is your first step.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way that I can think of is this first Activity

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, theOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Key, "Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

And on theOtherActivity

```
String receivedData=getIntent().getExtras().getKey(Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   // get the shared string from the SharedPreference
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Mysharedstring",0);
   String s = sp.getString("sharedString","Nothing found.");

   // display the shared string
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

---

Sources for SharedPreferences:

[How to save app settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353758/how-to-save-app-settings/19353944#19353944)

[How to keep information about an app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165818/how-to-keep-information-about-an-app-in-android/19440867#19440867)

[Shared Preferences | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)